Non-symmetric mutex
I have an unknown number of processes that create independent data, and one function that modifies all existing data. I need to be able to prevent the modification of data when it is being created (or conversely, the creation of data while the existing data is being modified), but not the parallel creation of data by multiple processes, since it is 100% independent data.
How to achieve this ? Is there an existing mechanism/pattern ?
If I use a mutex and lock it both in the process code and in the modification function code, then when one process locks the mutex, then no other process can start creating other data, even though I want to allow that.
I could have an infinite loop in the process code that just read whether the mutex is locked or not, but does not end up locking it. But doesn't that defeat the purpose of a mutex ?
I am writing in C++ with Qt 5.

Most likely you need real-time kernel. You didn't mention if you are using Windows or Linux based system. IIUC, your problem requires a higher priority task to be able to kick out low priority task, which is possible in RT systems. The other method that you can try is to use userspace Read-Copy-Update (RCU) approach, but not sure https://github.com/urcu/userspace-rcu.

QReadWriteLock is what I used. It offers a lock with two kinds of locking :

Write lock means nobody else can read or write
Read lock means nobody else can write, but anybody else can read in parallel.

In my case the "reading" is the creating of new independent data (so concurrent "reading" i.e. creating of new data can happen in parallel without issue)
"Writing" is the modification of all existing data : no new data can be created at that time.
Of course, Qt provides helpers for locking that will naturally unlock, even on exceptions and stuff :
#include <QReadWriteLock>
#include <QReadLocker>
#include <QWriteLocker>

QReadWriteLock processReadWriteLock;

void addData()
{
    QReadLocker readLocker(&processReadWriteLock);
    /* Create new, independent data */
    ...
}

void modifyData()
{
    QWriteLocker writeLocker(&processReadWriteLock);
    /* Modify all existing data */
    ...
}

More generally, the trick is to use two mutexes instead of one : one that prevents writing when reading (modifying when creating), and one that prevents reading when writing (creating when modifying). Qt just offers a native combined mutex.
